# Get-PnPListItem : Cannot complete this action

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, caml

I am trying to get an item in a SharePoint list using a CAML query so that I can update it. I am using data in a CSV file but when I run the script, it's failing on Get-PnPListItem. Based on some research I believe I'm getting this error because I have an error with the query. Does anyone know what the error is? The description field may be null in CSV which is why there's a conditional. Title and Location always have a value.

```
$data= Import-Csv "myPath\data.csv"

foreach ($item in $data) {
    $query = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $item.Title + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Location'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $item.Location + "</Value></Eq>"

    if($item.Description -eq $null) {
        $query += "<IsNull><FieldRef Name='Description'/></IsNull>"
    } else {
        $query += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Description'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $item.Description + "</Value></Eq>"
    }

    $query += "</And></Where></Query></View>"

    $spListItem = Get-PnPListItem -List "My SP List" -Query $query
}
```

Here is an example of what the query string looks like:

```
<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Grand Canyon</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Location'/><Value Type='Text'>Arizona</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Description'/><Value Type='Text'>National Park</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>
```

I have verified internal names are properly spelled. All field types in query are single line of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CAML query is invalid. In your example, you are trying to add 3 child elements to the And tag, while it only can have two. It means you are missing one more < And > tag:

Instead of this

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>Title</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Location'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>Location</Value>
                </Eq>   
                <!-- AND CANNOT HAVE 3 CHILD ELEMENTS: -->
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Description'/><Value Type='Text'>Description</Value></Eq>         
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

You need an extra And condition like so:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                        <Value Type='Text'>Title</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Location'/>
                        <Value Type='Text'>Location</Value>
                    </Eq>                    
                </And>              
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Description'/><Value Type='Text'>Description</Value></Eq>       
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```